Trying to change interpolation for an Object constraint animation property
I have a camera following a path around a bezier circle tracking to an empty. Normal 360 camera pan type thing. I want to change the interpolation to constant but the animation isn't turning up in the timeline or graph editor.

In the Graph editors menu bar, uncheck "display selected" (the arrow icon).

you have to select your camera to see the keyframes. That's a basic rule of Blender. You "normally" only see information to things that you have selected.

I had it selected, and couldn't understand why it wasn't showing... but checking it again I realised that I had the disabled restriction toggle on in the data outliner. Thank You Chris for replying, that really helped.
